# I2C Voltage levels with difference

Tags: i2c, pic16f

I have an I2C slave device in which the maximum input voltage to SCL & SDA is 3.6V. 
And the I2C Master device is PIC16F877A operating at 20MHz which provides a 5V output on SCL & SDA.

Pls help me to interface these two devices.

Comment: You need a bidirectional logic level shifter/converter..https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bi-directional-logic-level-converter-hookup-guide

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/97889/76228

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple level shifter that will allow you to interface the two devices. The levels shifter is perfect for I2C because it is bidirectional.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCNonx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can the person who down-voted this please explain why? It is not a terrible answer. Although this question could be closed, since it has been asked and answered multiple times.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but maybe a passive-aggressive user thought this is a dupe and as such it shouldn't get an answer. Just disregard the vote and move on... +1

Answer (score 1):

If there are no 5V slaves on your I2C bus you might well get by with connecting the pull-up resistors to 3.3V. The voltage on those resistors determine the bus voltage, not the connected chips.

A consequence is that the 877 will see a lower voltage than it expects (with a 5V bus), so you might need to run the bus at a lower speed.