# Voltage Amplifier circuit for PWM amplification

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog

I am using the **raspberry pi** to generate a **PWM signal** to feed the servo motor. The output voltage (Max) from a Rpi GPIO is 3.3V whereas I need it to be 5V for my specific application.
So I am thinking of using a Voltage amplifier, I have two choices:

1)A non-inverting amplifier like this:
[image]
Where Gain Av=Rf+R1/R1

2)A Transistor voltage amplifier something Like this:
[image]

**Questions:**

1)what would be the best choice?
2)considering the PWM frequency to be somewhere from 20-200KHz, Which one of those will provide the better output response?

Thankyou.

Comment: It depends what you're driving with the PWM signal. More information, please....

Comment: @Finbarr it a servomotor drive so current is not an issue .

Comment: But does it even need to be driven right up to 5V or is 3.3V sufficiently above its high input voltage for you to avoid amplifying it at all?

Comment: _Which_ servo motor drive?

Comment: @Finbarr high input Vtg is about 4.8V-5.5V so we need to amplify the voltage.

Comment: Its from Yaskawa I don't know the exact model number but those are the details the vendor gave me . PWM signal-20-2000KHz and 5V vtg .

Comment: You actually need a logic level converter.

Comment: @EnricBlanco Ohh !! just that ? That will do it ?

Comment: @Mr.Sky Look at this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97889/is-there-any-bidirectional-5v-3-3v-level-shifter

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few ways to do it. The simplest would be a transistor plus a collector resistor to the 5v rail. You can also use logic gates powered from 5v. Optocouplers, dedicated drivers, or even just a resistor or a diode. ... Or nothing.

All depends on the devices involved.