# si7021 with 5V MCU

Tags: i2c, 5v, 3.3v, open-drain

i need to connect [Si7021](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Weather/Si7021.pdf) wich is an 3.3v I2C humidity sensor with Arduino, 
this sensor has  open drain SCL and SDA drivers.
is it possible to connect this sensor directly to Arduino 5V?.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet explicitly says that the SCL/SDA pins are **not** 5V-tolerant, so you'll definitely need level shifters.

See [Is there any bidirectional 5v-3.3v level shifter?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97889/is-there-any-bidirectional-5v-3-3v-level-shifter)

Comment: but those pins are pulled-up to 3.3V not 5V...

Comment: Sorry, "those pins" refers to which pins exactly? Your question states that you're using a 5V Arduino.

Comment: the SDA and SCL pins of the sensor are pulled-up with 4.7K resistors.